# Standard input redirect from subdirectory in Fortran

Tags: linux, redirect, input, fortran

When I do the following cmd in the terminal: `/home/files/program < test.in` I would like my program to read the test.in file from `/home/files/tests` and not from `/home/files/` so basically read from `/home/files/tests/test.in` but I don't know how to do it in Fortran 90. I normally just do `read(5,*) ...` but now I need to access a subdirectory and I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

`/home/files/program < tests/test.in`

The connection of standard input to the file is handled by your shell, not the program proper.